# 'O_RDONLY', `F_SETFL`, 'O_NONBLOCK' undeclared errors while following OpenGL tutorial

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, codeblocks

I am currently learning modern OpenGl from the following website: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Building%20the%20Tutorials.html.

Unfortunately, when I follow the instructions to build the code examples, I fail.

This is what happens:

1- I run **premake4 codeblocks** in the glsdk directory.

2- I open **glsdk.workspace** in code blocks.

3- I go to Build -> Build workspace.

4- I get the error:

```
/home/hani/Desktop/Tutorial 0.3.8/glsdk/freeglut/src/freeglut_joystick.c In function ‘fghJoystickOpen’:|

/home/hani/Desktop/Tutorial 0.3.8/glsdk/freeglut/src/freeglut_joystick.c|1430|error: ‘O_RDONLY’ undeclared (first use in this function)|

/home/hani/Desktop/Tutorial 0.3.8/glsdk/freeglut/src/freeglut_joystick.c|1430|note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|

/home/hani/Desktop/Tutorial 0.3.8/glsdk/freeglut/src/freeglut_joystick.c|1448|error: ‘F_SETFL’ undeclared (first use in this function)|

/home/hani/Desktop/Tutorial 0.3.8/glsdk/freeglut/src/freeglut_joystick.c|1448|error: ‘O_NONBLOCK’ undeclared (first use in this function)|

/home/hani/Desktop/Tutorial 0.3.8/glsdk/freeglut/src/freeglut_joystick.c||In function ‘fghJoystickInit’:|

/home/hani/Desktop/Tutorial 0.3.8/glsdk/freeglut/src/freeglut_joystick.c|1597|error: ‘F_OK’ undeclared (first use in this function)|

||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

||=== Build: Debug in glload (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
||=== Build: Debug in glimg (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
||=== Build: Debug in freeglut (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
```

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04.
Help me solve this problem.

Comment: You're missing a header file, possibly `fcntl.h`, maybe `unistd.h`

Comment: @BenVoigt I just included fcnt1.h at the top of freeglut_joystick.c and it worked!!!! But now when I try to build the first tutorial I get:/usr/bin/ld: ../glsdk/freeglut/lib/libfreeglutD.a(freeglut_state.o)||glsdk.workspaceundefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'|

Comment: Do you know how to fix that error? Also, I was wondering how you came up with the reasoning that fcntl.h was missing? I had spent all day and could not figure anything out...

Comment: I've hit that missing header before.  Your new error indicates a missing library on your link line.  Haven't checked your instructions yet, to see if they give a clue.

Comment: You can find the missing library by running `pkg-config --libs x11`

Comment: For the second error I go to 'Tut 01 Hello Triangle' directory. I run premake4 codeblocks. I go to Tutorial1.workspace and then Build-> Build workspace.

Comment: Your command gave output: -lX11

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about premake4... but you need to add `-lX11` somewhere so that it ends up on the `ld` command line.  In a conventional makefile there's a variable named `LIBS` that you can add it to.

Comment: On how to know, that the fcntl.h include was missing? Easy: Just poke any of the reported missing tokens into Google (or `whatis` or `apropos` tools on the command line if you have made a manpage index on your system).

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this to work, what I did was use the **gmake** platform instead, then by going to the ***.make** file generated I added **-lx11** at the end of the line that begins with **LIBS** for both the debug and release options. Finally just run **make config=debug** and make **config=release** to get the executable files. Also, if you have multiple *.make files add -lX11 to all of them.